# Problems with Modulo in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Doing some practice runs on codecademy and came across the following problem: So the objective is to print "Fizz" if the numbers are divisible by 3. "Buzz" if the numbers are divisible by 5. And "FizzBuzz" if the numbers are divisible by both 3 and 5.

Here is my code, and I thought I had it right, but when I run it they tell me that my code is not 100% accurate. Looking to see any alternatives to this code, or what might be the issue... 
Code:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 21; i++)
{
  if (i % 3 == 0 )
  {
    console.log("Fizz");
  }

  if (i % 5 == 0)
  {
    console.log ("Buzz");
  }

  if ( i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 === 0)
  {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
  }   
  else 
  {
    console.log(i);
  }    
}
```

Comment: For start, Using `else if` would avoid printing both.

Comment: Seems you didn't understand the requirements. In the common fizzbuzz problem, the objective is to only print one of these per number.

Comment: I think you are only supposed to print one result for each number. Your code gives multiple outputs for a number, if multiple conditions match

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codecademy FizzBuzz app, stuck on step 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797834/codecademy-fizzbuzz-app-stuck-on-step-1)

Comment: Got it, so the 'else if' prevents all conditions from being printed...

Comment: You can do it in one line easily (see my answer below):    

`console.log(i%3?(i%5?i:'buzz'):(i%5?'fizz':'fizzbuzz'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `else if` to stop from other conditions executing:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same problem:

"Oops, try again. It looks like you printed out the wrong number of items."

Comment: @EdwardK. Yes. Because you want to run the loop 20 times

Answer (score 1):

It can easily be done in a one liner.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  console.log(i%3?(i%5?i:'buzz'):(i%5?'fizz':'fizzbuzz'));  
};
```

For a nice formatting also output `i` on each iteration:

```
for (i = 1; i < 21; ++i) {
  console.log(i+": "+(i%3?(i%5?i:'buzz'):(i%5?'fizz':'fizzbuzz')));  
};
```

Comment: Nice and succinct. How did you avoid the == to 0 bit?

Comment: I'm using the way Booleans work with **falsy** and **truthy** statements in Javascript. 

e.g. 9%3 is falsy, since it results to 0.

So 

`if(i%3)` is actually identical in result to `if(i%3!=0)`.

Comment: Nice, but you are able to avoid the if else statements with that little "?" you put in the code?

Comment: Yes, that the so-called ternary operator.

`a > b ? a : b;`

is actually identical to 

`if(a>b) { return a; } else { return b };`